# Hard time with lldb and signals. SIGSTOP issue

Tags: c, debugging, freebsd, lldb

I am used to `gdb`. Now, as I had switched to `FreeBSD`, I try to use `lldb`.

The program uses `kqueue` to wait on `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGQUIT` signals. Now if `lldb` attaches to the process, or runs target with command line arg, the debugger sends `SIGSTOP` signal. One thing is that `SIGSTOP` can't be ignored and wait on.

The problem is, that `kevent` returns `-1` on process resume and proceeds to quit. I can not see no output to `stderr`, that is another question being asked in different post.

What is a practice to deal with signals when `lldb` is a debugger?

**Update**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/event.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <yma/yerror.h>
#include <yma/ybsd_sock.h>

#define TERMINATE_SET(s, v, l) { EXPAND(s) = v; PRINT_ERROR() goto EXPAND(l);  }

#define NSIGNALS (5)
#define NSOCKETS (2)
#define SIGNALS  {SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGTERM, SIGCONT, SIGPIPE}
#define NKEVBACKLOG (NSIGNALS + (NSOCKETS * 4)) /* signals + socket reads/writes + socket error + eof */
#define BUFSIZE  (1024)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 (void)argc;
 (void)argv;

 /* program status */
 int status = 0;

 /* restore signals at program exit ? */
 bool b_restore_procmask = false;

 /* signal masks */
 sigset_t         mask_block_sigs, mask_save_sigs, mask_kqueue_sigs;

 struct kevent    chlist[10];            /* events to monitor */
 struct kevent    evlist[NKEVBACKLOG];   /* events that were triggered */
 int              kq = -1, i, n;

 /* signals being monitored by kqueue */
 int signals[] = SIGNALS;

  /* create kqueue descriptor */
  if((kq = kqueue()) < 0){
   TERMINATE_SET(status, -1, l_end)
  }

 /* set up signals */ 
 sigemptyset(&mask_block_sigs);
 /* these signals will be blocked. the signals will arrive */
 /* to kqueue and not to a default signal handler.          */
 for(i = 0; i < NSIGNALS; ++i){
  sigaddset(&mask_block_sigs, signals[i]);  
 }

 /* save old sigmask, replace it with new sigmask */
 status = sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask_block_sigs, &mask_save_sigs);
 TERMINATE_IF(status < 0, l_end)

 b_restore_procmask = true;

 /* set signal event */
 for(i = 0; i < NSIGNALS; i++){
  EV_SET(&chlist[i], signals[i], EVFILT_SIGNAL, EV_ADD, 0, 0, 0);
 }
 /* end of signal setup */

 /* add signals change list to kqueue */
 n = kevent(kq, chlist, NSIGNALS, NULL, 0, NULL);
 if(n < 0){
  TERMINATE_SET(status, -1, l_end)
 }

 /* event loop */
 while( 1 ) {
  
  /* see event list */
  n = kevent(kq, NULL, 0, evlist, NKEVBACKLOG, NULL);

  switch(n) { /* switch on kevent return */
   /* timeout */
   case 0: 
    break;
   /* error */
   case -1:
    TERMINATE_SET(status, -1, l_end);
   /* some events */
   default: {
    int ev_id;
    
    /* process events */
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
     ev_id = evlist[i].ident;

     /* check if signal has arrived */
     switch(ev_id){
      case SIGINT:
      printf(" ! got SIGINT\n");
      goto l_end;
     case SIGQUIT:
      printf(" ! got SIGQUIT\n");
      goto l_end;
     case SIGTERM:
      printf(" ! got SIGTERM\n");
      goto l_end;
     case SIGPIPE:
      printf(" ! got SIGPIPE\n");
      break;
     default: break;
    }
   } break; /* end process events */
  } /* end kevent return switch */
 } /* end event loop */

l_end:

 /* restore procmask */
 if(b_restore_procmask && (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask_save_sigs, NULL) < 0)){
  PRINT_ERROR()
 }
 /* close kqueue */
 CLOSE(kq);

 return status;
}
```

The above is a complete source of a program that waits on `POSIX` signals.

I do not want to include my makefile, as it is irrelevant here. Something like `clang -std=c2x -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wfatal-errors -O0 -g3 -glldb -fpic -c kevent.c -o outp` should go.

**Update**

The program is indeed exits with "Interrupted system call"

**Update**

As I read again through the code, I've found an error. The error was in misplaced `ev_id` initialization. The initialization were before `for` event loop. So the above code reacts to `SIGINT` as expected.

**Update**

But again, when I attach to process, and not run it as an argument to `lldb`, I am being confused again. If I send `SIGINT` to the process, `lldb` is ignoring the fact that `process handle SIGINT -s false -p true` and quits with "Interrupted system call."

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post the [relevant] code. What is the value of `errno`? What does your `kevent` code do? Does it _retry_ the call if `errno` is `EINTR` [as it _should_] or was this not thought of? Also, AFAICT, `kevent` is a BSD thing. What did your program use under [I presume] linux? But, again, do you handle `EINTR` properly?

Comment: @CraigEstey Hello. Thanks for the remarks. I completely forgot about the fact that `syscalls` can be interrupted. And found an error in the code. Now the program runs fine as a "local" target. But I have, again, a hard times when I attach to an already running program.

Comment: @CraigEstey I did use `epoll_pwait` under `Linux`.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks, retry of `kevent` solved the problem. I think that `lldb` do rewrite a process signal mask on attach. And that was the reason.